# Shell script run by Jenkins creates non-terminating process

Tags: bash, git, jenkins

I'm trying to use Jenkins to create a special git repository. I created a free-style project that just executes a shell script. When I execute this script by hand, without Jenkins, it works just fine.
From Jenkins, however, it behaves quite differently.

```
# this will remove all subtrees
git log | grep git-subtree-dir | tr -d ' ' | cut -d ":" -f2 | sort | uniq | xargs -I {} bash -c 'if [ -d $(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)/{} ] ; then rm -rf {}; fi'

rm -rf .git
```

If this part is executed by Jenkins, in console output I see this kind of errors:

```
rm: cannot remove '.git/objects/pack/pack-022eb85d38a41e66ad3f43a5f28809a5a3ee4a0f.pack': Device or resource busy
rm: cannot remove '.git/objects/pack/pack-05630eb059838f149ad30483bd48d37f9a629c70.pack': Device or resource busy
rm: cannot remove '.git/objects/pack/pack-26f510b5a2d15ba9372cf0a89628d743811e3bb2.pack': Device or resource busy
rm: cannot remove '.git/objects/pack/pack-33d276d82226c201eedd419e5fd24b6b906d4c03.pack': Device or resource busy
```

I modified this part of the script like this:

```
while true
do
    if rm -rf .git ; then
        break
    else
        continue
    fi
done
```

But this doesn't help. In the task manager I see a git process that just doesn't terminate.
I conjured said script by a lot of googling and I do not understand very good what's going on.

Jenkins runs on Windows Server 2012 behind IIS; shell scripts are executed by bash shipped with git for Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, aparrently I was able to fix my issue by running the script from different user.
By default on Windows Jenkins executes all jobs from the user SYSTEM. I have no idea why it affects the behaviour of my script but running it with `psexec` from specially created user account worked.

In case anyoune is interested, I did something like this:

```
psexec -accepteula -h -user Jenkins -p _password_ "full/path/to/bash.exe" full/path/to/script.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

1/ Ensure your path is correct, and no quote/double quote escaping occurs in the process of jenkins job starting.

2/ Your command line is a bit too handy to be correctly and safely evaluated.
Put your commands in a regular script, starting with `#!/bin/bash` instead of thru the command line.

```
xargs -I {} bash -c 'if [ -d $(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)/{} ] ; then rm -rf {}; fi'
```

becames

```
xargs -I {} /path/myscript.sh {}
```

with

```
#!/bin/bash

rev-parse="$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)"
wait

if [ -d ${rev-parse}/${1} ] ; then 
   rm -rf ${1}
fi
```

Please note that your script is *really* unsafe, as you `rm -rf` a parameter without even evaluate it before… !

3/ You can add a `wait` between the `git` and the `rm` to wait for the end of the git process

4/ log your git command into a log file, with a redirection `>> /tmp/git-jenkins-log`

5/ put all of those commands in a script (see #2)

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean by `Please note that your script is really unsafe, as you rm -rf a parameter without even evaluate it before… !`

Comment: rm -rf is a destructive operation and can be applyied to any part of the filesystem. You _must_ check twice before using such a command.
If your path to rm is a constant, it's right.
If it is a variable, you _have_ to check and source the content.
In your case, it is an external content, which could be anything, as you dont verify it.
Are you sure somebody has not injected by some way a “/” or a “/ home/git” (please note the space) in the git result, left part of the xarg ?

Comment: I checked the argument of `rm -rf` and it is correct. I tried adding a wait - that did not help. I don't know how to check what process is using those .pack files, since my bash lacks `lsof` or `lslock` and they probably won't work since its all on Windows anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Following is an infinite loop in case `rm -rf` fail

```
while true
do
    if rm -rf .git ; then
        break
    else
        continue
    fi
done
```

indeed `continue` can be used in `for` or `while` loop to get the next entry but in this while loop it will run the same `rm` command forever.

Comment: I added this loop just to try `rm` several times. I believe it's not the real problem because `rm` can't remove files anyway.

Comment: the problem is `while true` + `continue` never ends

Comment: I removed else branch entirely but it didn't help; those files are still not removed.